# Sound won't play at a specific time in unity

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a sound play with the timer goes to 3, 2, 1.

My timer starts at ten and has a three second delay.  If I use the following code:

```
    if (tl.myCoolTimer == 10)
    {
        print("Play Sound");
        myAudioSource.Play();
    }
```

It plays the Beep over and over again until the game starts and the counter goes below 10.

If I use the code:

```
    if (tl.myCoolTimer == 3)
    {
        print("Play Sound");
        myAudioSource.Play();
    }
```

It doesn't play the sound at all.  It doesn't even print the print statement.

I literally only changed the number.  I am not sure why this isn't working.

I have also tried setting it to 3f  to see if it is a float issue.

Timer Scripts

This is the starting Timer.  it counts down to 3 (then the game starts)

```
public Text startGameTimerText;

public float startGameTimer = 3;

public void Start ()
{
    startGameTimerText = GetComponent<Text> ();
}


public void Update ()
{

    startGameTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    startGameTimerText.text = startGameTimer.ToString ("f1");

    if (startGameTimer < 0) {
        GameObject.Find ("GameStartTimer").SetActive (false);
    }

}
```

This is the Game Timer It starts at 10 and counts down to 0.

```
public StartGameTimer gt;  //this is the script the other timer is on

public Text timerText;

public float myCoolTimer = 10;

public void Start ()
{
    timerText = GetComponent<Text> ();
}

public void Update ()
{
    if (gt.startGameTimer > 0) {
        myCoolTimer = 10;
    } else {
        myCoolTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = myCoolTimer.ToString ("f1");
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Tim, it's likely you're trying to compare a float, instead of an int.  Google on this, can't be answered here there are 1000000s pages on it.  be sure to change to an In.  note that if you use Debug.Log. you can instantly find the problem.  BTW you should be using InvokeRepeat for this.  cheers

Comment: show us your timer code , maybe the problem is in your timer

Comment: My biggest issue is that I just change the number and it doesn't work.  It doesn't even recognize the code.  If I put it back to 10 it works appropriately.  Change it to 9 it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `gt.startGameTimer` here? And how you are updating it?

Comment: My guess is your `gt.startGameTimer` is remain > 0 and your `myCoolTimer` is always `10`. And in this `if (tl.myCoolTimer == 10)` condition, obviously it is true, so either it is executing everytime or your `myAudioSource` component has `Loop` activated

Comment: Loop is not activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Joe for the help.  Here was my final answer.  I know it is hacked, but I haven't figured out the Invoke thing yet.  When I set the into it kept playing the entire time it was at "3", so i need to make it play only once.

```
private AudioSource myAudioSource;
public bool isSoundPlayed;

void Start()
{
    myAudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    isSoundPlayed = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if((int)tl.myCoolTimer == 3)
    {
        if (isSoundPlayed == false)
        {
            myAudioSource.Play();
            isSoundPlayed = true;
        }
        return;
    }
    if ((int)tl.myCoolTimer == 2)
    {
        if (isSoundPlayed == true)
        {
            myAudioSource.Play();
            isSoundPlayed = false;
        }
        return;
    }
    if ((int)tl.myCoolTimer == 1)
    {
        if (isSoundPlayed == false)
        {
            myAudioSource.Play();
            isSoundPlayed = true;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```